# Bootstrap like jQuery UI theme

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to migrate away from jQuery UI to Twitter Bootstrap in long run.

- I am not using all the features of jQuery UI, only a bit of them. It's too heavy.
- I would be abilize to utilize the responsive design page grid code of Bootstrap which jQUI does not provide
- I know jQuery UI and Twitter are not compatible (currently), but I don't indent to run them parallel

However, the first step would be make to site styles look like more the default Twitter Bootstrap styles. Are there any Bootstrap like themes for jQuery UI or any themes utilizing the same LESS files as Bootstrap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a work-in-progress project that is trying to mashup the two frameworks under the Bootstrap styles, though it is still at work i believe it should make do in the meantime.

Here is the [project page](https://github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui-bootstrap)